# Adding two lines for each category in horizontal axis scatterplot(ggplot2)

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have this dataset:

```
workdataset <- data.frame(dadedu=rep(c("ISCED 1 & 2", "ISCED 3 & 4", "ISCED 5 & 6"),each=2),
                          socialorigin=rep(c(1,0),times=3),
                          Level = rep(c("Below ISCED 1", "ISCED 1", "ISCED 2", "ISCED 3", "ISCED 4","ISCED 5", "ISCED 6"), each=6),
                          Prob = rnorm(42))
```

And I produced this plot:

```
ggplot(workdataset, aes(x = Level, y = Prob, colour = dadedu)) +
        geom_point(aes(group=dadedu, size=0.2)) + geom_line()
```

As you can see in each category in the horizontal axis, there are two points of the same color connected through a line. Instead of having that, I'm trying to have two lines for each category where, for example, both red dots are connected with a line, and so on for the other colors. And then, differentiating both lines in the category by a different shape of the dot.

I've been playing around with facet_grid but I am still not quite familiarized with ggplot2 and  I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

---

EDIT:
I'm sorry I didn't explain myself correctly but I'll give it another try. So as you can see in the plot there are several categories in the horizontal axis(Below ISCED 1, ISCED 2, etc..). For each category, right now there is one vertical line containing 6 dots(2 red, 2 green and 2 blues). 1 red belongs to socialorigin = 1 and the other red equals to social origin = 0. What I want is, instead of one vertical line with 6 dots, two vertical lines with 3 dots each. So one vertical line would be socialorigin=1 and the other socialorigin=0, and then connect with a line the red dot from vertical line 1 with the red dot from vertical line 2, and so on for the other colors. That is for all categories in the horizontal axis(ISCED 1, ISCED 2 etc). If this is still unclear, I'll try and show an image that emulates what I want.

Hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: I am afraid your question is not clear to me (and apparently not to @jeremycg either), not even after reading the comment below jeremycg's answer. Can you maybe specify an example of row numbers in your database you want connected with a line and row numbers you want to have the same shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I think this is it?
It takes a little hack work, as we are joining dodged points with a line. First let's build the base plot:

```
p <- ggplot(workdataset, aes(x = Level, y = Prob, group = socialorigin, colour = dadedu)) + 
         geom_point(aes(shape = dadedu), position = position_dodge(width = 0.50))
```

Now we want to use `ggplot_build` to get the data out:

```
newdat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]
```

`newdat` is now the x and y, group and colour for our plot. We need to get a new var to group by - a combination of shape, colour and x (here rounded due to the dodge):

```
newdat$group2 <- paste0(newdat$shape, newdat$colour, round(newdat$xmin))
```

And then add it to the plot:

```
p + geom_line(data = newdat,aes(x,y, group = group2), colour = newdat$colour)
```

[image]

Previous answer follows:

I think you need to create a new variable for the combination of `socialorigin` and `dadedu`:

```
workdataset$comb <- paste0(workdataset$dadedu, workdataset$socialorigin)
```

Which we can then use to group the lines by, and use the `socialorigin` to make the point shapes:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(workdataset, aes(x = Level, y = Prob, colour = dadedu)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = factor(socialorigin)), size = 3) +
    geom_line(aes(group = comb))
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: I probably didn't explain myself correctly. For example, for the 'Below ISCED 1' category I want two lines, one for social origin=1 and the second one with social origin=0(right now a color is repeated twice in the single line; you can see at as a pre and post treatment lines). Then I'd like to connect the same colored dots for those two lines. So see the change from 1 line to the other. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: I think the new edit is what you wanted? If it's not, draw a picture of what you want.

Comment: Yes Jeremy, that was it. Thanks a lot.